# making matplotlib scatter plots from dataframes in Python's pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dataframe, pandas

What is the best way to make a series of scatter plots using `matplotlib` from a `pandas` dataframe in Python?

For example, if I have a dataframe `df` that has some columns of interest, I find myself typically converting everything to arrays:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
# df is a DataFrame: fetch col1 and col2 
# and drop na rows if any of the columns are NA
mydata = df[["col1", "col2"]].dropna(how="any")
# Now plot with matplotlib
vals = mydata.values
plt.scatter(vals[:, 0], vals[:, 1])
```

The problem with converting everything to array before plotting is that it forces you to break out of dataframes.

Consider these two use cases where having the full dataframe is essential to plotting:

1. For example, what if you wanted to now look at all the values of `col3` for the corresponding values that you plotted in the call to `scatter`, and color each point (or size) it by that value? You'd have to go back, pull out the non-na values of `col1,col2` and check what their corresponding values.

   Is there a way to plot while preserving the dataframe? For example:

   ```
   mydata = df.dropna(how="any", subset=["col1", "col2"])
   # plot a scatter of col1 by col2, with sizes according to col3
   scatter(mydata(["col1", "col2"]), s=mydata["col3"])
   ```
2. Similarly, imagine that you wanted to filter or color each point differently depending on the values of some of its columns. E.g. what if you wanted to automatically plot the labels of the points that meet a certain cutoff on `col1, col2` alongside them (where the labels are stored in another column of the df), or color these points differently, like people do with dataframes in R.  For example:

   ```
   mydata = df.dropna(how="any", subset=["col1", "col2"]) 
   myscatter = scatter(mydata[["col1", "col2"]], s=1)
   # Plot in red, with smaller size, all the points that 
   # have a col2 value greater than 0.5
   myscatter.replot(mydata["col2"] > 0.5, color="red", s=0.5)
   ```

How can this be done?

**EDIT** Reply to crewbum:

You say that the best way is to plot each condition (like `subset_a`, `subset_b`) separately. What if you have many conditions, e.g. you want to split up the scatters into 4 types of points or even more, plotting each in different shape/color. How can you elegantly apply condition a, b, c, etc. and make sure you then plot "the rest" (things not in any of these conditions) as the last step?

Similarly in your example where you plot `col1,col2` differently based on `col3`, what if there are NA values that break the association between `col1,col2,col3`? For example if you want to plot all `col2` values based on their `col3` values, but some rows have an NA value in either `col1` or `col3`, forcing you to use `dropna` first. So you would do:

```
mydata = df.dropna(how="any", subset=["col1", "col2", "col3")
```

then you can plot using `mydata` like you show -- plotting the scatter between `col1,col2` using the values of `col3`. But `mydata` will be missing some points that have values for `col1,col2` but are NA for `col3`, and those still have to be plotted... so how would you basically plot "the rest" of the data, i.e. the points that are *not* in the filtered set `mydata`?

Comment: Things changes in the meantime, see [Plotting - Plotting - Scatter plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#scatter-plot) from the official documentation.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try passing columns of the `DataFrame` directly to matplotlib, as in the examples below, instead of extracting them as numpy arrays.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=['col1','col2'])
df['col3'] = np.arange(len(df))**2 * 100 + 100

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
       col1      col2  col3
0 -1.000075 -0.759910   100
1  0.510382  0.972615   200
2  1.872067 -0.731010   500
3  0.131612  1.075142  1000
4  1.497820  0.237024  1700
```

#### Vary scatter point size based on another column

```
plt.scatter(df.col1, df.col2, s=df.col3)
# OR (with pandas 0.13 and up)
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='col1', y='col2', s=df.col3)
```

[image]

#### Vary scatter point color based on another column

```
colors = np.where(df.col3 > 300, 'r', 'k')
plt.scatter(df.col1, df.col2, s=120, c=colors)
# OR (with pandas 0.13 and up)
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='col1', y='col2', s=120, c=colors)
```

[image]

#### Scatter plot with legend

However, the easiest way I've found to create a scatter plot with legend is to call `plt.scatter` once for each point type.

```
cond = df.col3 > 300
subset_a = df[cond].dropna()
subset_b = df[~cond].dropna()
plt.scatter(subset_a.col1, subset_a.col2, s=120, c='b', label='col3 > 300')
plt.scatter(subset_b.col1, subset_b.col2, s=60, c='r', label='col3 <= 300') 
plt.legend()
```

[image]

#### *Update*

From what I can tell, matplotlib simply skips points with NA x/y coordinates or NA style settings (e.g., color/size).  To find points skipped due to NA, try the `isnull` method: `df[df.col3.isnull()]`

To split a list of points into many types, take a look at [numpy `select`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), which is a vectorized if-then-else implementation and accepts an optional default value.  For example:

```
df['subset'] = np.select([df.col3 < 150, df.col3 < 400, df.col3 < 600],
                         [0, 1, 2], -1)
for color, label in zip('bgrm', [0, 1, 2, -1]):
    subset = df[df.subset == label]
    plt.scatter(subset.col1, subset.col2, s=120, c=color, label=str(label))
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: great answer! I didn't know about these. I usually get my data into the format I like and send it over to R for ggplot. These examples will let me do a lot more within pandas/python - thanks.

Comment: How can I make single circle with specific size in legend?

Answer (score 8):

There is little to be added to Garrett's great answer, but pandas also has a [`scatter` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html). Using that, it's as easy as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=['col1','col2'])
df['col3'] = np.arange(len(df))**2 * 100 + 100
df.plot.scatter('col1', 'col2', df['col3'])
```

[image: plotting sizes in col3 to col1-col2]

Answer (score 5):

I will recommend to use an alternative method using `seaborn` which more powerful tool for data plotting. You can use `seaborn scatterplot` and define colum 3 as `hue` and `size`.

**Working code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

#creating sample data 
sample_data={'col_name_1':np.random.rand(20),
      'col_name_2': np.random.rand(20),'col_name_3': np.arange(20)*100}
df= pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
sns.scatterplot(x="col_name_1", y="col_name_2", data=df, hue="col_name_3",size="col_name_3")
```

[image]