# pyplot.scatter(dataframe) vs. dataframe.plot(kind='scatter')

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have several pandas dataframes. I want to plot several columns against one another in separate scatter plots, and combine them as subplots in a figure. I want to label each subplot accordingly. I had a lot of trouble with getting subplot labels working, until I discovered that there are two ways of plotting directly from dataframes, as far as I know; see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300137/making-matplotlib-scatter-plots-from-dataframes-in-pythons-pandas) and [pandasdoc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
ax0 = plt.scatter(df.column0, df.column5)
type(ax0): matplotlib.collections.PathCollection
```

and

```
ax1 = df.plot(0,5,kind='scatter')
type(ax1): matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
```

`ax.set_title('title')` works on `ax1` but not on `ax0`, which returns
 `AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'set_title'`

I don't understand why the two separate ways exist. What is the purpose of the first method using PathCollections? The second one was added in 17.0; is the first one obsolete or has it a different purpose?

Comment: Since this may be useful to anyone visiting the question, I have found `df.plot(0,5,style='.')` to work better than `df.plot(0,5,kind='scatter')` since the former will work after using groupby() whereas the latter does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found, the pandas function returns an axes object. The PathCollection object can be interpreted as an axes object as well using the "get current axes" function. For instance:

```
plot = plt.scatter(df.column0, df.column5)
ax0 = plt.gca()
type(ax0)
```

> < matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x10d2cde10>

A more standard way you might see this is the following:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = plt.add_subplot()
ax0.scatter(df.column0, df.column5)
```

At this point you are welcome to do "set" commands such as your `set_title`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that they are from different libraries. The first one is from matplotlib, the second one from pandas. They do the same, which is create a matplotlib scatter plot, but the matplotlib version returns a collection of points, whereas the pandas version returns a matplotlib subplot. This makes the matplotlib version a bit more versatile, as you can use the collection of points in another plot.