# ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg when using plot_date()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame of test results that looks like this:

```
   TestName                Date  IsPassed
0     test1 2017-01-31 21:44:30         0
1     test1 2017-01-31 21:39:00         0
2     test1 2017-01-31 21:38:29         1
3     test1 2017-01-31 21:38:27         1
4     test2 2016-10-31 05:05:02         0
5     test3 2016-12-07 20:58:36         0
6     test3 2016-12-07 20:57:19         0
7     test3 2016-12-07 20:56:15         0
8     test4 2016-12-05 18:50:49         0
9     test4 2016-12-05 18:49:50         0
10    test4 2016-12-05 03:23:09         1
11    test4 2016-12-04 23:51:29         1
```

Now I want to plot the tests against the dates so that the points would have different colors based on the outcome. Here is what I do. Note that I use the approach outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300137/making-matplotlib-scatter-plots-from-dataframes-in-pythons-pandas). I'm using Python 3.5.

```
# factorize cases
labels, test = pd.factorize(test_df['TestName'])
tests = test_cases.copy()
tests['TestName'] = labels

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = np.where(tests.IsPassed > 0, 'r', 'g')
ax.plot_date(tests.Date, tests.TestName, color=colors)
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2016-10-28'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04'))
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
plt.show()
```

And this code results in the following error:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: 
Invalid rgba arg "['g' 'g' 'r' 'r' 'g' 'g' 'g' 'g' 'g' 'g' 'r' 'r']"
length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4
```

**Update**

Based on the comments from @Marcos Modenesi this code works. But is there a way to avoid repetition and make the solution more Pythonic?

```
# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
passed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 1]
failed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 0]
ax.plot_date(passed.Date, passed.TestName, color='g')
ax.plot_date(failed.Date, failed.TestName, color='r')
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2016-10-28'), pd.Timestamp('2017-02-04'))
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: By reading [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html), I'm guessing  `color` should be a single color, not a list of colors.

Comment: I'm TOTALLY thinking out loud here, but I'd go with what you're trying to do in a simpler way. First I'd plot green dots with `ax.plot_date(tests.Date[passed], tests.TestName[passed], color='g')` where `passed = np.where(tests.IsPassed > 0)`. Then I'd plot red dots with an equivalent approach.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it should. But the question is: how do I achieve different colors for different outcomes?

Comment: I got your idea, but I guess it should be something like:
`passed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 1]
    failed = tests[tests.IsPassed == 0]
    ax.plot_date(passed.Date, passed.TestName, color='g')
    ax.plot_date(failed.Date, failed.TestName, color='r')`

Comment: Avoiding repetition can be done with `for`-loops. Are `for` loops unpythonic?