# How to add legend to scatter plot that has colour assignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter

I have an a list of x and y values and list of colour assignments for each point ('green', 'blue', 'red', etc). All of the examples I have found produce a legend based on separate plt.scatter() commands which later a simple plt.legend() suffices. [making matplotlib scatter plots from dataframes in Python's pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300137/making-matplotlib-scatter-plots-from-dataframes-in-pythons-pandas). My scatter does not have separate scatters for each coloured group. So how do I produce a legend that shows the colours of each group?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple", "gray"]
regions = ["Hanoi", "Nha Trang", "Vung Tau", "Phu Quoc", "Quang Ngai", "Saigon"]
region_colors=dict(zip(regions,colors))

grp_color=[]
for i in data['Region']:
    grp_color.append(region_colors[i]) 

x_long=data[' Longitude']
y_lat=data[" Latitude"]
plt.scatter(x_long,y_lat,c=grp_color)
plt.legend(grp_color,regions,loc='right')
```

Comment: The logic is reversed here. Usually the easiest way to produce a legend for a scatter plot with different colors is to split the data up, plot different scatter plots (or normal plots) and use `plt.legend()`.

Comment: so i should go back to the dataframe and split it up so I can plot each group separately?

Comment: That certainly is an option. You can also use my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of colors 
`colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]` and a list of regions `regions = ["Africa", "America", "Australia"]`
you can create a list of legend handles and use it to create the legend:

```
handlelist = [plt.plot([], marker="o", ls="", color=color)[0] for color in colors]
plt.legend(handlelist,regions,loc='right')
```

Comment: thanks for your quick suggestion, I am getting this error message with your code: "ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "Islands"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "Islands"
could not convert string to float: 'islands''

Comment: ok, its because my region_colors is a dictionary, so I replaced region_colors with region_colors.values(). but the legend does not show anything, its just a white square

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should directly work for you.

Comment: fantastic, it worked. thanks so much! why do we only take the first element of the handlelist?

Comment: We only take the first element of the list of lines and put it into the `handlelist`. `plt.plot()` returns a list of lines (in this case only one) and we need that item from the list, instead of the list itself.

Comment: i've been looking for this answer for so long, thank you!