# How do I create a scatter plot for this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter

Below is my dataset. I can't create a scatter plot for this using:

```
data.plot.scatter(x="",y="")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the text of that dataframe? Or better yet the code to create that dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300137/making-matplotlib-scatter-plots-from-dataframes-in-pythons-pandas Try referring this

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame contains lists in the "Vol" column, so to plot it, you will need to somehow get the values from them. Let's assume you want to plot R and the first value in Vol. You can try something like this:

```py
plt.scatter(x=df.R, y=df.Vol.apply(lambda y: y[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply slice the content of the column by using the index of the item you want to use in the plot. You can use the matplotlib framework and slice the list using a lambda function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['R'], df['Vol'].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
```